# MySQL Workbench Error 1064 Error

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

I'm aware that this question has been asked multiple times. I'm working on my assignment which is to create a database for a car insurance company. Encountered a syntax issue.

After trying to run my code I get an error:

```
    Executing SQL script in server
ERROR: Error 1064: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'Primary key,
  `Address` VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL DEFAULT 'Persons Address',
  `Add' at line 5
SQL Code:
        -- -----------------------------------------------------
        -- Table `insurance`.`DriverAddress`
        -- -----------------------------------------------------
        CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `insurance`.`DriverAddress` (
          `Address_ID` MEDIUMTEXT NOT NULL DEFAULT Primary key,
          `Address` VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL DEFAULT 'Persons Address',
          `Address2` VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL DEFAULT 'Additional line',
          `City` VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL DEFAULT 'City',
          `County` VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL DEFAULT 'County',
          `SortCode` VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL DEFAULT 'Sort Code',
          `Country` VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL DEFAULT 'Country',
          PRIMARY KEY (`Address_ID`))
        ENGINE = InnoDB

SQL script execution finished: statements: 5 succeeded, 1 failed

Fetching back view definitions in final form.
Nothing to fetch
```

My table look like this:

```
-- MySQL Workbench Forward Engineering

SET @OLD_UNIQUE_CHECKS=@@UNIQUE_CHECKS, UNIQUE_CHECKS=0;
SET @OLD_FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=@@FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS, FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0;
SET @OLD_SQL_MODE=@@SQL_MODE, SQL_MODE='TRADITIONAL,ALLOW_INVALID_DATES';

-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Schema insurance
-- -----------------------------------------------------

-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Schema insurance
-- -----------------------------------------------------
CREATE SCHEMA IF NOT EXISTS `insurance` DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8 ;
USE `insurance` ;

-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `insurance`.`DriverAddress`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `insurance`.`DriverAddress` (
  `Address_ID` MEDIUMTEXT NOT NULL DEFAULT Primary key,
  `Address` VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL DEFAULT 'Persons Address',
  `Address2` VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL DEFAULT 'Additional line',
  `City` VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL DEFAULT 'City',
  `County` VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL DEFAULT 'County',
  `SortCode` VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL DEFAULT 'Sort Code',
  `Country` VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL DEFAULT 'Country',
  PRIMARY KEY (`Address_ID`))
ENGINE = InnoDB;


-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `insurance`.`Policy Table`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `insurance`.`Policy Table` (
  `Policy_ID` MEDIUMTEXT NOT NULL DEFAULT Auto Incrament,
  `Policy Number` NVARCHAR(20) NOT NULL DEFAULT 'Policy Number',
  `PolicyEffectiveDate` DATETIME NOT NULL DEFAULT Effective Date,
  `PolicyExpireDate` DATETIME NOT NULL DEFAULT Policy Expire Date,
  `PaymentOption` DATETIME NOT NULL DEFAULT Designated payment time,
  `TotalAmount` DOUBLE NOT NULL DEFAULT Total policy amount,
  `Active` TINYINT(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT If expired, false unless renew,
  `AdditionalInfo` TEXT NULL DEFAULT 'Hidden info for staff',
  `CreateDate` DATETIME NOT NULL,
  `DriverAddress_ID` MEDIUMTEXT NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`Policy_ID`),
  CONSTRAINT `fk_Policy Table_DriverAddress1`
    FOREIGN KEY (`DriverAddress_ID`)
    REFERENCES `insurance`.`DriverAddress` (`Address_ID`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
ENGINE = InnoDB;

CREATE INDEX `fk_Policy Table_DriverAddress1_idx` ON `insurance`.`Policy Table` (`DriverAddress_ID` ASC);


-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `insurance`.`PolicyEditLog`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `insurance`.`PolicyEditLog` (
  `Log_ID` MEDIUMTEXT NOT NULL DEFAULT Auto incrament,
  `EditedTableName` VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL DEFAULT 'Name of the table when record is applied',
  `EditedDate` DATETIME NOT NULL DEFAULT When is the record put into the DB,
  `EditedBy` VARCHAR(50) NULL DEFAULT 'Who updated the record',
  `AdditionalInfo` TEXT NULL DEFAULT 'Extra information for the staff',
  `Policy Table_ID` MEDIUMTEXT NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`Log_ID`),
  CONSTRAINT `fk_PolicyEditLog_Policy Table1`
    FOREIGN KEY (`Policy Table_ID`)
    REFERENCES `insurance`.`Policy Table` (`Policy_ID`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
ENGINE = InnoDB;

CREATE INDEX `fk_PolicyEditLog_Policy Table1_idx` ON `insurance`.`PolicyEditLog` (`Policy Table_ID` ASC);


-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `insurance`.`Payment Table`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `insurance`.`Payment Table` (
  `Payment_ID` MEDIUMTEXT NOT NULL DEFAULT Auto incrament,
  `PaidDate` DATETIME NOT NULL DEFAULT Payment made date,
  `Amount` DOUBLE NOT NULL DEFAULT How much paid,
  `PaymentMethod` VARCHAR(100) NULL DEFAULT 'What way it was paid',
  `PaymentFirstName` VARCHAR(50) NULL DEFAULT 'First name on card',
  `PaymentLastName` VARCHAR(50) NULL DEFAULT 'Last name on card',
  `CardNumber` VARCHAR(50) NULL DEFAULT 'front number of the card',
  `BackCode` VARCHAR(10) NULL DEFAULT 'three digits at the back of the card',
  `CardExpiryDate` VARCHAR(10) NULL DEFAULT 'When does it expire',
  `CardType` VARCHAR(20) NULL DEFAULT 'visa/maestro etc.',
  `DebitOrCredit` VARCHAR(50) NULL DEFAULT 'Is it a debit or a credit card?',
  `BankName` VARCHAR(100) NULL DEFAULT 'The actual name of the bank',
  `AccountNumber` VARCHAR(20) BINARY NULL DEFAULT 'In case person decides to use DD',
  `BankCode` VARCHAR(20) NULL DEFAULT 'The 6 digit area code of the bank',
  `ChequeNumber` VARCHAR(20) NULL DEFAULT 'If it\'s been paid with a cheque',
  `ChequeImage` VARCHAR(20) NULL DEFAULT 'Image of the cheque',
  `AdditionalInfo` TEXT NULL DEFAULT 'Additional information',
  `CreatedDate` DATETIME NULL DEFAULT When was the account created,
  PRIMARY KEY (`Payment_ID`))
ENGINE = InnoDB;


-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `insurance`.`Bill`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `insurance`.`Bill` (
  `BILL_ID` MEDIUMTEXT NULL DEFAULT Auto incrament,
  `DueDate` DATETIME NOT NULL DEFAULT Payment due date,
  `MinimumPayment` DOUBLE NOT NULL DEFAULT Minimum payment or per bill payment,
  `CreatedDate` DATETIME NOT NULL DEFAULT Bill generated date,
  `Balance` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL DEFAULT 'Remaining balance if part payment is made',
  `Status` NVARCHAR(50) NOT NULL DEFAULT 'Paid/Unpaid',
  `Policy Table_ID` MEDIUMTEXT NOT NULL,
  `Payment Table_ID` MEDIUMTEXT NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`BILL_ID`),
  CONSTRAINT `fk_Bill_Policy Table`
    FOREIGN KEY (`Policy Table_ID`)
    REFERENCES `insurance`.`Policy Table` (`Policy_ID`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
  CONSTRAINT `fk_Bill_Payment Table1`
    FOREIGN KEY (`Payment Table_ID`)
    REFERENCES `insurance`.`Payment Table` (`Payment_ID`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
ENGINE = InnoDB;

CREATE INDEX `fk_Bill_Policy Table_idx` ON `insurance`.`Bill` (`Policy Table_ID` ASC);

CREATE INDEX `fk_Bill_Payment Table1_idx` ON `insurance`.`Bill` (`Payment Table_ID` ASC);


-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `insurance`.`Driver`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `insurance`.`Driver` (
  `Driver_ID` MEDIUMTEXT NOT NULL DEFAULT Primary Key,
  `Title` VARCHAR(50) NULL DEFAULT 'Mr, Mrs etc.',
  `FirstName` VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL DEFAULT 'Name of the driver',
  `SurName` VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL DEFAULT 'Surname of the driver',
  `MiddleInitial` VARCHAR(1) NULL DEFAULT '1 letter of the middle name',
  `DoB` VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL DEFAULT 'Date of birth',
  `EmailAddress` VARCHAR(100) NULL DEFAULT 'Can be null if user doesnt have one',
  `PhoneNumber` VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL DEFAULT 'Driver Home Phone number',
  `MobileNumber` VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL DEFAULT 'Mobile number',
  `LicenseIssuedDate` DATE NOT NULL DEFAULT License issued date,
  `LicenseCountry` VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL DEFAULT 'where is the license from',
  `LicenseNumber` VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL DEFAULT 'Driver license number',
  `Gender` VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL DEFAULT 'Sex',
  `MartialStatus` VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL DEFAULT 'Martial Status',
  `CreatedDate` DATETIME NOT NULL DEFAULT When was it created,
  `Active` TINYINT(1) NULL DEFAULT if driver is still using services or not,
  `Policy Table_ID` MEDIUMTEXT NOT NULL,
  `DriverAddress_ID` MEDIUMTEXT NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`Driver_ID`),
  CONSTRAINT `fk_Driver_Policy Table1`
    FOREIGN KEY (`Policy Table_ID`)
    REFERENCES `insurance`.`Policy Table` (`Policy_ID`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
  CONSTRAINT `fk_Driver_DriverAddress1`
    FOREIGN KEY (`DriverAddress_ID`)
    REFERENCES `insurance`.`DriverAddress` (`Address_ID`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
ENGINE = InnoDB;

CREATE INDEX `fk_Driver_Policy Table1_idx` ON `insurance`.`Driver` (`Policy Table_ID` ASC);

CREATE INDEX `fk_Driver_DriverAddress1_idx` ON `insurance`.`Driver` (`DriverAddress_ID` ASC);


-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `insurance`.`Vehicle`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `insurance`.`Vehicle` (
  `Vehicle_ID` MEDIUMTEXT NOT NULL DEFAULT Auto incrament,
  `Year` CHAR(4) NOT NULL DEFAULT 'year',
  `Make` VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL DEFAULT 'make',
  `model` VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL DEFAULT 'model',
  `Colour` VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL DEFAULT 'colour',
  `Mileage` INT(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT mileage,
  `number plate` VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL DEFAULT 'number plate',
  `CreatedDate` VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL DEFAULT 'when was this car added',
  `Additional notes` VARCHAR(100) NULL DEFAULT 'If necessary for example requires repair etc.',
  `Active` TINYINT(1) NULL DEFAULT Has vehicle been removed or not,
  `Policy Table_ID` MEDIUMTEXT NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`Vehicle_ID`),
  CONSTRAINT `fk_Vehicle_Policy Table1`
    FOREIGN KEY (`Policy Table_ID`)
    REFERENCES `insurance`.`Policy Table` (`Policy_ID`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
ENGINE = InnoDB;

CREATE INDEX `fk_Vehicle_Policy Table1_idx` ON `insurance`.`Vehicle` (`Policy Table_ID` ASC);


-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `insurance`.`Vehicle_Driver`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `insurance`.`Vehicle_Driver` (
  `Incrament_ID` MEDIUMTEXT NOT NULL DEFAULT Auto Incrament,
  `CarPurpose` BIT NULL DEFAULT Is it for business or personal,
  `PredictedMilage` INT NULL DEFAULT How many miles do you expect to drive,
  `CreatedDate` DATETIME NULL DEFAULT when was it added,
  `Active` TINYINT(1) NULL DEFAULT Is it active/deactivated,
  PRIMARY KEY (`Incrament_ID`))
ENGINE = InnoDB;


-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `insurance`.`Coverage`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `insurance`.`Coverage` (
  `Coverage_ID` MEDIUMTEXT NOT NULL DEFAULT Auto increment,
  `CoverageName` VARCHAR(100) NULL DEFAULT 'Name of coverage',
  `CoverageGroup` VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL DEFAULT 'Rental, jobless, gap etc.',
  `Code` VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL DEFAULT 'Group for each business option',
  `IsPolicyCoverage` BIT NOT NULL DEFAULT Does it apply only for the policy coverage,
  `IsVehicleCoverage` BIT NOT NULL DEFAULT Doesi t apply only for the vehicle coverage,
  `DriverStatus` VARCHAR(45) NULL DEFAULT 'His current driver rating',
  `Description` BIT NULL DEFAULT additional info,
  `PolicyEditLog_ID` MEDIUMTEXT NOT NULL,
  `Vehicle_Driver_ID` MEDIUMTEXT NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`Coverage_ID`),
  CONSTRAINT `fk_Coverage_PolicyEditLog1`
    FOREIGN KEY (`PolicyEditLog_ID`)
    REFERENCES `insurance`.`PolicyEditLog` (`Log_ID`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
  CONSTRAINT `fk_Coverage_Vehicle_Driver1`
    FOREIGN KEY (`Vehicle_Driver_ID`)
    REFERENCES `insurance`.`Vehicle_Driver` (`Incrament_ID`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
ENGINE = InnoDB;

CREATE INDEX `fk_Coverage_PolicyEditLog1_idx` ON `insurance`.`Coverage` (`PolicyEditLog_ID` ASC);

CREATE INDEX `fk_Coverage_Vehicle_Driver1_idx` ON `insurance`.`Coverage` (`Vehicle_Driver_ID` ASC);


SET SQL_MODE=@OLD_SQL_MODE;
SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=@OLD_FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS;
SET UNIQUE_CHECKS=@OLD_UNIQUE_CHECKS;
```

I will be extremely grateful if someone could guide me in the right direction.

Comment: There are a lot of inconsistencies and typos, so I think you should start over writing this with one table at a time, confirm it works, then move on to the next. Or use Workbench modeling instead and then generate the SQL. For example "Auto incremant" is a typo. Also, it appears you are mixing comments with default values, and some are in quotes whereas others are not.

Answer (score 1):

You have DEFAULT primary key .. try instead without default in first row  eg:  AUTO_INCREMENT or nothing

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `insurance`.`DriverAddress` (
      `Address_ID` MEDIUMTEXT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
      `Address` VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL DEFAULT 'Persons Address',
      `Address2` VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL DEFAULT 'Additional line',
      `City` VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL DEFAULT 'City',
      `County` VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL DEFAULT 'County',
      `SortCode` VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL DEFAULT 'Sort Code',
      `Country` VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL DEFAULT 'Country',
      PRIMARY KEY (`Address_ID`))
    ENGINE = InnoDB
```